# Why is the matrix $K$ representing generator for Lorentz transformation matrix symmetric while generators have to be antisymmetric?

Tags: special-relativity, operators, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

While deriving the generators for rotation and velocity transformation i got the matrix for Lorentz tranformation as symmetric matrices? While i have read that generators have to antisymmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context: I am referring to the action of the Lorentz group in coordinates
$$\mathbb{R}^4 \ni x \mapsto \Lambda x \in \mathbb{R}^4\:.$$
also called the fundamental representation of the Lorentz group.
And I am considering a boost transformation along the $j$th spatial axis:$$\Lambda_s = \exp(sK_j)\:.$$

It is here false that generators $K_j$ is antisymmetric.

It is instead true that the generators are anti Hermitian for unitary representations of Lie groups or  antisymmetric for when referring to subgroupos  of $O(n)$ and its funamental representations in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Lorentz group is not unitary nor a subgroup of $O(n)$.

Comment: As many categorical answers this is not a complete answer to the OP question so it might be misleading for some. The fact is that generators are represented by tensors, not just mixed indices tensor matrices. When put in covariant form with the Lorentz metric the symmetric matrix for boosts is indeed an antisymmetric tensor in general, which of course doesn't imply it must be antisymmetric as a mixed tensor matrix precisely due to the peculiarities of the Minkowski metric.

Comment: You are right. I added some context.